# Make the iBooks search useful

Tags: ipad, books

Is it possible to make the iBooks search useful? It seems to totally lack any way of forcing capitalisation or word boundaries. I would use Regular Expressions if necessary.

By way of example I was searching a Python book for the word "Eric" but could find no way of stopping it telling me the thousands of references to num**eric** or num**eric**al